Firebase Android Push Notification using HTTP V1 giving error as SENDER_ID_MISMATCH
I'm trying to integrate Firebase Android Push Notification using HTTP V1 in Codeigniter 4 (PHP). As per latest documentation, i'm able to fetch Bearer Access Token using credential JSON file which is downloaded from Firebase account. And by using that Access Token, when i'm trying to send a Push Notification to the Device Token, i'm getting error as "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH". Below is the PHP code and response -
        function test_android_push_notification() {
            $scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging';
            $appName = 'XXXXX_App';
    
            $client = new \Google\Client();
            $client->setAuthConfig('PATH_OF_THE_JSON_FILE.json');
            $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
            $client->setScopes($scope);
            $client->setApplicationName($appName);
            $access_token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
            $bearerToken = $access_token['access_token']; // BEARER TOKEN RECEIVED

            //HTTP V1 API end-point
            $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID_HERE/messages:send';
    
            $token = trim($this->request->getPost('token')); // DEVICE TOKEN
            $data = array("message" => array("token" => $token, "data" => array("score" => "83", 'time' => "15:30"), "android" => array("direct_boot_ok" => true)));
            //header with content_type api key
            $headers = array(
                'Content-Type:application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $bearerToken
            );
            //CURL request to route notification to FCM connection server (provided by Google)          
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
            } else {
                echo '-----Notification Sent';
            }
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }

----- Below is the response ----
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SenderId mismatch",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "SENDER_ID_MISMATCH"
      }
    ]
  }
}

As the error code says, Sender ID is not matching, i'm not using Sender ID parameter anywhere in my code and this is not present in credentials JSON too. What could be the reason and how to fix the issue ?

Finally I found the reason for error code that i'm receiving for Firebase Push Notification response. The app developer were using the wrong Project ID to generate the device token. So, because of the Project ID was not matching to the credential JSON stored on Server, the error 'SEMDER_ID_MISMATCH' was appearing in response.
